# mostrar un div si algunos campos no estan vacios

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo algunos input que necesito validar y tengo un input con id "mostrar" oculto con hide();

quiero mostrar ese input si por ejemplo sueldo y puesto no estan vacios los demas input que tengo pueden estar vacios.

me quede atascado con el if por que tengo que aplicar una funcion en caso de que no esten vacios pero no se me ocurre nada

```
if($('#sueldo').val() != ''){
            $('#mostrar').show();
        }



<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                    <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label">Disponibilidad</label>
                          <label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Lunes">
                              Lunes
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Martes" >
                              Martes
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Miercoles">
                              Miercoles
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Jueves" >
                              Jueves
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Viernes">
                              Viernes
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" value="Sabado" >
                              Sabado
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" value="Domingo" >
                              Domingo
                            </label>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
                          <label>Horario entrada</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker"  id="entrada" name="Datos[horarioEntrada]">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                              <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
                          <label>Horario salida</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker"  id="salida" name="Datos[horarioSalida]">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label class="control-label">Fecha de solicitud</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="6"  name="Datos[fechaSolicitud]"  id="fechaSolicitud" value="<?php echo date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d");?>" readonly> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label class="control-label">Puesto</label>
                        <select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="Datos[puesto]"  ="" id="puesto">
                        <?php 
                        foreach ($puestos as $puesto){
                        ?>                            
                        <option  value="<?php echo $puesto['idPuesto']?>"><?php echo $puesto['nombre']?></option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?> 
                        </select> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label">Sueldo deseado</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" step="0.01"   name="Datos[sueldo]"   id="sueldo" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

<div id="mostrar">Mostrar</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es primero atacharte a un evento, yo te sugiero lo hagas por clase como te muestro en el siguiente ejemplo (el cual puedes ejecutar) para no tener que atacharte por cada control, luego en el evento llamas a la validación, una función que se encargue de retornar un valor booleano si el formulario es correcto, y de esta manera poder decidir si valida que acción se toma y si no CC.

```js
function validoFrm(){
  return (($('#Sueldo').val() != '') &&($('#Puesto').val() != -1));
}



$(function(){

$('.ValidoCLass').hide();

$('.requerido').change(function(){
  if(validoFrm()){
    $('.ValidoCLass').show();
  } else{
    $('.ValidoCLass').hide();
  }
});


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<label>Sueldo</label>
<input type="number" id="Sueldo" class="form-control requerido">

<label>Puesto</label>
<Select id="Puesto" class="form-control requerido">
<option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
<option value="1">Puesto 1</option>
<option value="2">Puesto 2</option>
<option value="3">Puesto 3</option>
</select>
</br>
<label class="ValidoCLass">Se validaron los campos sueldo y Puesto</label>
<input class="ValidoCLass form-control" type="text" id="CampoValidado"/>
```

Saludos!

Comment: gracias haci lo voy hacer

Comment: Por nada, me alegro que te haya sido de ayuda :) Saludos!

Comment: disculpa tuviera que hacer lo mismo pero con otro div oculto?

Comment: Cada Grupo de validaciones requiere que se escriba la lógica correspondiente, por ende deberías elegir un nombre de clase que se relacione con la validación correspondiente, así como el nombre de la función para que el código sea auto descriptivo, por ejemplo podría ser **Campo-ShowHide-SueldoPuesto** el nombre de la class para el inlut del ejemplo y la funcion **ValidoFrmSueldoPuesto()** y para los input que van a asociarse a la validación **requerido-SueldoPuesto** Cualquier duda dime ;)

Answer (score 0):

Para poder comprobar los inputs vacios, primero hay que tomar sus eventos. En tu caso pueden ser `change()`, `keyup()`, `keydown()`, entre otros.

Evento change con jQuery

```
$('#sueldo').on('change', function(){
    if($('#sueldo').val() != ''){
            $('#mostrar').show();
    }
    else{
           $('#mostrar').hide();
    }
});
```

Es más efectivo medir el la longitud del valor **val().length** para validar inputs vacios.

```
if($('#sueldo').val().length > 0)
                $('#mostrar').show();
        else
               $('#mostrar').hide();
```

Comment: tengo como 80 input no veo recomendable hacer lo mismo por cada uno

Comment: Usa las clases. recuerda que los selectores de jQuery son # numerales para ids y . puntos para las clases.